# PayPal Billing Agreement with further non regular Reference Transactions

Tags: php, soap, paypal

I am implementing PayPal payment to my application.
I am using Laravel Framework and merchant-sdk-php package to handle NVP/SOAP API. I would accually prefer REST API, but i need customers to make Reference Transactions with various amount, in non regular time periods and as far as i know it's possible only with NVP/SOAP API.

The payment flow in shortcut:

1. Payer clicks "connect" button, which is to create billing agreement using "SetExpressCheckout" method. Amount is set to 0 and adding a Billing Agreement field to request. Customer is redirected to PayPal, log in to his account, agreeing to direct debit and finally redirected to my return url.

2. After response is come, return action is fired (the one, which is passed in returnurl field). Next using token from paypal resposne i use CreateBillingAgreement method to get "BillingAgreementID" which i store in database.

3. Using "BillingAgreementID" i make "DoReferenceTransaction" request. No prompt to login is occurring, everything is happening behind the scene. Finally i get response after transaction.

The thinks i want to know are:

1. Is there a way, to get an email address, which consumer used to log in when creating billing agreemenet? I want to show in application which PayPal account (related to mentioned email) is direct debit set to?

2. I want to make some action in databse both after "BillingAgreementID" and "DoReferenceTransaction". Is the response status "Success" and additionally in "DoReferenceTransaction" field "PaymentStatus" set to "Completed" enought to conclude, that transaction is fully completed, and i cant i.e. share some digital goods or should i wait for IPN from this request?

Thanks for all contributions!

Answer (score 0):

Found solution to question 1.
After betting billing agreement id i had to make "GetBillingAgreementCustomerDetails" action. In response i got customer details including email.

Still watching for hint to second question